# .bash_history stops at 10000 lines

Tags: bash, command-history

I work in a cluster with mobaxterm. The typed commands are saved in the .bash_history .
But my problem is that .bash_history stops at 10000 lines. Then, the older commands in the beginning of the file are deleted and the newest commands are in the newest are in the end of the file.

Is there are way (for instance by modifying the .bash_profile file) to have all the commands without the limit of 10000 lines in my file?

Dimitris

Comment: I recommend against not having limits on your bash history file. It will make it endlessly grow and need manual cleanup.

Comment: Read `man bash` See my answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals/80882#80882 for a better way. Loading more than 10K lines into `bash` history every time you start `bash` will slow you down.

Comment: If you used some command 9999 commands ago and never recalled it from the history since then, is it actually important? How do you even remember its existence? 10,000 is a good chunk of a natural language vocabulary.

Comment: Make a backup every month or so. Write a script, to remove the duplicates. Maybe you use HISTTIMEFORMAT to identify the new stuff.